# jQuery and HTML - clicking on current div box id to display sub dvi box content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a my jQuery and HTML code.

my goal is when I click on the current box1, box2 or box3 , I want to display current sub box.

For example : when I click on current box1 should be open current sub_box_1, and so. I did some jQuery code but I can't get result.

Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sub_box').hide();
  $('.box').click(function() {
    $(this).$('#sub_box_1').show();
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.sub_box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #09c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapp">

    <div id="1" class="box">
      <b>Box 1</b>

      <div id="sub_box_1" class="sub_box">
        <input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder='User Name' />
        <button>ADD</button>
      </div>
      <!--sub_box_1-->
    </div>
    <!--1-->

    <div id="2" class="box">
      <b>Box 2</b>
      <div id="sub_box_2" class="sub_box">
        <input type="text" name="user_email" placeholder='User Email' />
        <button>ADD</button>
      </div>
      <!--sub_box_2-->
    </div>
    <!--2-->

    <div id="3" class="box">
      <b>Box 3</b>
      <div id="sub_box_3" class="sub_box">
        <input type="text" name="user_phone" placeholder='User Phone' />
        <button>ADD</button>
      </div>
      <!--sub_box_3-->
    </div>
    <!--3-->

  </div>
  <!--wrapp-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: change `$(this).$('#sub_box_1').show();` to `$(this).find('.sub_box').show();`

Comment: thank you very much Michael Coker.  great , it is working . good job

Answer (score 3):

Try using this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sub_box').hide();
  $('.box').click(function() {
    $(this).children('.sub_box').show();
  });
});
```

jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/d6zf0n1b/

Comment: just a note that `.find(".sub_box")` can be used as well.

Comment: thanks for your help. I tried your code and it is working perfect too

Answer (score 0):

When you are using $(this).$('#sub_box_1'). you are trying to execute the $ function of the return of $(this). There is no $ function of $(this). Hence you are getting an error.

The other problem is that you are trying to access by the "#" accessor which matches the id not the class.

So this is why Andre's answer works. He is starting from the box that was clicked and looking for immediate children that have the class "sub_box".

One thing to keep in mind is that the children method will only search one level down from the parent. If the box could be deeper down, you should use the 'find' method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `jQuery` `find` method (https://api.jquery.com/find/), which will find elements inside the the element matching the selector you use, try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sub_box').hide();
  $('.box').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.sub_box').show();
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.sub_box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #09c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapp">

    <div id="1" class="box">
      <b>Box 1</b>

      <div id="sub_box_1" class="sub_box">
        <input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder='User Name' />
        <button>ADD</button>
      </div>
      <!--sub_box_1-->
    </div>
    <!--1-->

    <div id="2" class="box">
      <b>Box 2</b>
      <div id="sub_box_2" class="sub_box">
        <input type="text" name="user_email" placeholder='User Email' />
        <button>ADD</button>
      </div>
      <!--sub_box_2-->
    </div>
    <!--2-->

    <div id="3" class="box">
      <b>Box 3</b>
      <div id="sub_box_3" class="sub_box">
        <input type="text" name="user_phone" placeholder='User Phone' />
        <button>ADD</button>
      </div>
      <!--sub_box_3-->
    </div>
    <!--3-->

  </div>
  <!--wrapp-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @user3559269 You're welcome, kindly mark it as the correct answer for future references